# Vertically align minipages caption (no subfigures used)

Tags: captions, vertical-alignment, minipage

After aligning a table and a plot horizontally I want them to be vertically aligned at the top of their captions(see last image). I have found solutions using subfigures or the floatrow package but both methods seem to be inappropriate here.
This is my setup so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=140pt]{test}
\captionof{figure}{First image with very very very very very very very very long caption}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{table with short caption}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want them to be aligned like this, but use captions of different length:

[image]

Comment: You will probably have to use four minipages instead. Maybe the `floatrow` package may be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=140pt]{test}
\captionof{figure}{First image with very very very very very very very very long caption}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}[table with short caption]{table with short caption\\\mbox{}\\\mbox{}}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```